# How can I format a numeric Data Label in SAP Crystal Reports to use dot as decimal separator, rather than comma?

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, decimal, report, separator

Being actually experienced in Crystal Reports, now it drives me crazy. Numeric Data Labels on bar charts format with dot as thousands separator and comma as decimal separator. But it should be the other way round.

[Wrong number formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiRIB.png)

Unfortunately, Crystal Reports built in Data Label formatting options do not allow for selecting separator symbols

[Format Data Labels not sufficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZoPu.png)

What I've already tried to fix the issue, meaning to get dots as decimal separators:

1. General settings in Crystal Reports (File -> Options -> Fields -> Number... -> Number)
   [General numeric field settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AemuP.png)
2. De-installed Crystal Reports, changed all Windows regional settings to English number formats and reinstalled Crystal Reports
   [Windows regional settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvR53.png)
3. Creating generic new report file with generic data from Excel data source - same results

I am running Windows 11 Pro and Crystal Reports 2020 SP1 64 BIT (Version 14.3.1.3701). My report is pulling data via ODBC Driver 17 from Microsoft Azure SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Simon, Can you upload a simple rpt file with some saved data and I will inspect the report here? I know in Scandinavia the dot and comma are reversed as you describe so it could be the database setup.